# modeling or analysing programs that deal with filters and cycles like sed

Tags: filter, sed, analysis

when faced with a problem that needs a filtering mechanism like sed, how do you analyse or model the problem so that you can solve it with sed? i am asking this question because I have found that deconstructing a sed program that solves a problem into its analytical constituents is very difficult for me. doing analysis targeted towards the sed solution space which involves filtering and cycles really beats me.

Comment: You look at the data and then create a program in `awk` `sed` `perl` or other program that solves the problem.  `sed` is good to simple task, `awk` and `perl` do more complex tasks.

Comment: awk works with table data or columns, sed with line and streams etc. I know that. I read lots of codes on sed but if faced with a question, an a priori question, I cannot write a code in sed. analysis fails me. I wonder how to go about it, especially where the program should contain filters and cycles. thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should think in sed way of working (read a line, treat it and go to the next) so basically
sed Find and change pattern of charactere
sed could work with a cumulative buffer of line (1 buffer as memory and 1 buffer for direct action) and they can be manipulate like adding one to another, replacing or swapping
also, there is a test mecanisme that occur after a substitution

one big thing is that, by default sed work only 1 line at a time. It read the loine from the input and treat it than go to the next cycle. This mean, without buffering, no Carriage return on the line and one line cannot "see" another one.

sed is very efficient for quite simple task, could do very hard work (like games) but need to think not like a c/pascal/awk/shell script and often you need to pass through temporary situation like adding think or replace by a temporary pattern before going back to what you expect a bit like working on Reverse Polish in terms of computation.
Best is to give us a small concept problem and we try to show you the way we (there are ofter several ways) solve it

Comment: thanks. forum is still open. working on preparing something on logo for kids. will be back in about i>30 days time. hope u do understand.